# How to connect my host to Redis cluster network on docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, redis

I'm running this [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/itsmetommy/docker-redis-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml) on my machine (Mac with docker desktop) but am not able to connect the cluster with `redis-cli`.

I'm running it with

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I'm able to run `redis-cli` **from within the containers** like

```
❯ docker exec -it docker-redis-cluster_redis-1_1 redis-cli -c -p 7001                                                                                       (eks-dev-blue/itamar)
127.0.0.1:7001> cluster nodes
c9c01ea75f43780f36f3dca445410c1c902bda0b 10.0.0.16:7006@17006 slave cc69a5c2467fff36daa62acefc70b4b49d7a22a6 0 1643633817569 2 connected
cc69a5c2467fff36daa62acefc70b4b49d7a22a6 10.0.0.12:7002@17002 master - 0 1643633816000 2 connected 5461-10922
9c1d48c16402c651578b4722ceb699aa0effa392 10.0.0.11:7001@17001 myself,master - 0 1643633816000 1 connected 0-5460
c83836c357ce77cf845cda983aa76aa7942e2489 10.0.0.14:7004@17004 slave 5bdf05a8d332646ee76ff0da64fb97570cf7117e 0 1643633816558 3 connected
5bdf05a8d332646ee76ff0da64fb97570cf7117e 10.0.0.13:7003@17003 master - 0 1643633817974 3 connected 10923-16383
115b037e3dc2de23389a3b085b4242b63bfa887a 10.0.0.15:7005@17005 slave 9c1d48c16402c651578b4722ceb699aa0effa392 0 1643633817000 1 connected
```

But I'm not able to communicate with the cluster from my host machine:

```
❯ redis-cli -c -h localhost -p 7001                                                                                                                                       (eks-prod-blue/prod)
127.0.0.1:7001> cluster nodes
Error: Server closed the connection
```

What am I missing? Is it a missing network\ports config?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the following network and your services get IPs from this range.

```
  redisnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/16
```

Which container are you connecting to? Does the IP get resolved correctly? Does your host machine know how to reach the 10.0.0.0/16 subnet? You need to have a entry in your route table that sends the traffic for 10.0.0.0/16 through the bridge adapter created for the `redisnet` network.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to config my host machine to use this subnet

Comment: Use the route -n command to see all your routes. Check if one exists for 10.0.0.0/16 and which device is displayed as the gateway. If you don't see any, then you need to list all your interfaces with ifconfig -a and find the one that is of type bridge and has an address in the 10.0.0.0/16 subnet. Use the ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 dev <device-you-found> command to add the route.